# PyGTK: Need help scrolling multiple TextViews together

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am trying to write a text viewer widget with PyGTK that displays line numbers alongside the main viewing window. Of course I want the line numbers and main window to scroll in sync with each other. I can't figure out how to get this to work, though. Right now I am doing this. TextViewer is a subclass of HBox that creates the two TextViews and packs them into itself under the attribute names linenums and mainview.

```
self.textviewer = TextViewer.TextViewer(self.toplevel)

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
sw.set_vadjustment(self.textviewer.mainview.get_vadjustment())
sw.set_hadjustment(self.textviewer.mainview.get_hadjustment())

sw.add_with_viewport(self.textviewer)

sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
```

If I take out the two set_Xadjustment lines, then the embedded TextViews' scroll_to_mark function doesn't work, which isn't acceptable for my application. With them in, the main text window scrolls twice as quickly as the line number window, and vice versa if I set the ScrolledWindow's adjustments to those of self.textviewer.linenums. I strongly suspect that this is a bug. I also tried setting up the viewport myself and setting its adjustments to those of one of the TextViews, but again the scroll_to_mark functions stop working. How can I synchronize both TextViews to scroll as one, so that any scrolling changes to one of them equally affect the other?

EDIT: Here is the code in my main application where I set up the widget.

```
self.textviewer = TextViewer.TextViewer(self.toplevel)

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
#These are the lines that toggle between the two problems when (un)commented
sw.set_vadjustment(self.textviewer.mainview.get_vadjustment())
sw.set_hadjustment(self.textviewer.mainview.get_hadjustment())

sw.add_with_viewport(self.textviewer)

sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
```

Comment: I have the same problem; using a hbox is not possible because the two widgets are always independent. One widget actually shows the line numbers, so I also only need to sync all scroll-actions in the main text-view area, with that other widget. I don't know how to connect scrolling events though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having difficulty understanding exactly how you've got the two `gtk.TextView`s packed in the `HBox`. Are they both packed in separate `gtk.ScrolledWindow` that are then packed inside of the `HBox` which is then packed into another `gtk.ScrolledWindow`(The one mentioned in your post)? From what it sounds like to me, both of these `gtk.TextView`s are packed in their own `gtk.ScrolledWindow` within your `TextViewer` wrapper widget.

If this is the case, a simple solution to your issue, granted that the two `gtk.TextView`s are the same height(so the line numbers line up with the main view), I suggest simply packing them inside your `Hbox` without `ScrolledWindow`s. Then you can use your code above, adding them that `ScrolledWindow` and the viewport will move the two collectively as if they are one widget.

If this isn't your issue, could you please supply some more information about your TextViewer wrapper, and maybe some more sample code?

Also: You may be interested in [gtksourceview](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtksourceview/class-gtksourceview.html). With the gtksourceview2 package, you get an instance of the View widget:

```
import gtksourceview2
view = gtksourceview2.View()
```

Comment: They are both packed directly into the HBox/TextViewer widget, which is then added to the outer ScrolledWindow (with a Viewport). There is only one ScrolledWindow. And yes, they should contain the same number of lines. Again, my problem isn't that I can't scroll them together; it's that I cant scroll them together and be able to use the scroll_to_mark function at the same time.

Comment: How do I import and use gtksourceview? I added it to my installation, but I still can't seem to import it.

Comment: @dpitch40 Added more clarity to the gtksourceview in my answer above

Comment: Is this package documented? Why is there no gtksourceview package as described in the documentation?

Comment: Sorry, I believe this package is deprecated and gtksourceview2 has replaced it. I can't seem to find any online documentation for it, but you should be able to find the documentation in your filesystem. I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and it's located under /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/pygtksourceview2/index.html.  Hope that helps, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check how it is implemented in Meld.  In particular, the [filediff code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/meld/tree/meld/filediff.py) (search search for sync there).